# Data-placeholder in chosen select raise error on validator.w3

Tags: jquery, select

In my laravel 5.7/ blade / jQuery v3.3.1 / Bootstrap v4.1.2 app 
I use https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ library (Version 1.8.7) and it works, but I found a small bug with data-placeholder
I define select input as :

```
<select class="form-control editable_field chosen_select_box" id="chosen_customer_type" name="chosen_customer_type" onchange="javascript:chosenSelectionOnChange('customer_type'); " data-placeholder=" -Choose customer type- "  >
    <option value=""  selected ></option>
    <option value="SS" >SS</option
    ><option value="RS" >RS</option>
</select>↩
```

I have to set first element as element with empty key  and label to make data-placeholder be visible when no value is selected for this select input.
I found such decision in internet and without this empty element data-placeholder does not work.

> But testing with https://validator.w3.org I got next error: Error:
>   Element option without attribute label must not be empty. From line
>   199, column 254; to line 199, column 262 selected >

I would like to fix this error in https://validator.w3.org output.

I init chosen inputs with JS code:

```
$(".chosen_select_box").chosen({
    disable_search_threshold: 10,
    allow_single_deselect: true,
    no_results_text: "Nothing found!",
});
```

and such chosen inputs looks like : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKJuz.jpg
where for the top no element selected and the second element has element selected and it has deselect image, which is set by allow_single_deselect option
in the code above.

If there is a way to get rid of these https://validator.w3.org errors ?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a wild idea, but have you tried putting a `label` attribute on the placeholder option and set its value to non empty (or perhaps set its value equal to the `data-placeholder` attribute value)? ➝ `<option value=""  label="  -Choose customer type- " selected ></option>`

Comment: Sorry I did not understand what do you mean. Could you please give example ?

Comment: IronGeek, I tried what you proposed. No, it does not work. " -Choose customer type- "  is rendered as item with empty value, not placeholder.

Comment: Worth pointing out explicitly: your error is with the missing label attribute, as he describes, not with data-placeholder itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple snippet of what I'm suggesting before in the comment.

Based on this snippet if we added a `label` attribute to a placeholder `<OPTION>` beforehand, then the final HTML markup generated by chosen is valid enough to pass the W3C validator, while otherwise failed:

```
<select class="... chosen_select_box" data-placeholder=" -Choose customer type- ">
    <option value="" label=" -Choose customer type- " selected ></option>
    ...
</select>
```

> Notice the `data-attribute` on the `select` element and the `label` attribute on the `option` element is set to the same value, this is not required. `Chosen` will use the `data-attribute` on the `select` element for placeholder while the `label` attribute on `option` is only there to satisfy the W3C validation.

```js
$(".chosen_select_box").chosen({
    disable_search_threshold: 10,
    allow_single_deselect: true,
    no_results_text: "Nothing found!",
});

function chosenSelectionOnChange(type) {
  console.log(type);
}
```

```css
select {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

This should pass WC3 validation:
<select class="form-control editable_field chosen_select_box" id="chosen_customer_type1" name="chosen_customer_type" onchange="javascript:chosenSelectionOnChange('customer_type'); " data-placeholder=" -Choose customer type- "  >
    <option value="" label=" -Choose customer type- " selected ></option>
    <option value="SS" >SS</option
    ><option value="RS" >RS</option>
</select>
<hr>
This does not pass WC3 validation:
<select class="form-control editable_field chosen_select_box" id="chosen_customer_type2" name="chosen_customer_type" onchange="javascript:chosenSelectionOnChange('customer_type'); " data-placeholder=" -Choose customer type- "  >
    <option value=""  selected ></option>
    <option value="SS" >SS</option
    ><option value="RS" >RS</option>
</select>
```